# WSO2 Service Provider API updateApplication failing

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to create / update a service provider in WSO2 Identity Server through SoapUI. I have taken the reference from the below document.
  https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Using+the+Service+Provider+API#UsingtheServiceProviderAPI-updateApplication

I am able to createApplication, getApplication using SoapUI successfully.

However when I try to updateApplication it fails. Below is the soap request , response and logs.

SOAP request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://model.common.application.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsd:updateApplication>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:serviceProvider>
            <xsd1:applicationID>2</xsd1:applicationID>
 <xsd1:description>updated description</xsd1:description>            
         </xsd:serviceProvider>
      </xsd:updateApplication>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAP Response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method updateApplication</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Following is the related logs from wso2carbon.log :

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-27 15:04:50,043] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provisioning.listener.ProvisioningApplicationMgtListener} -  Clearing cache entry for null 
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-27 15:04:50,044] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl} -  Using local cache 
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-27 15:04:50,044] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} -  Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method updateApplication 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.provisioning.cache.ServiceProviderProvisioningConnectorCacheKey.hashCode(ServiceProviderProvisioningConnectorCacheKey.java:62)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
at org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl.get(CacheImpl.java:194)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.cache.BaseCache.getValueFromCache(BaseCache.java:158)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.provisioning.listener.ProvisioningApplicationMgtListener.destroySpProvConnectors(ProvisioningApplicationMgtListener.java:76)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.provisioning.listener.ProvisioningApplicationMgtListener.doPreUpdateApplication(ProvisioningApplicationMgtListener.java:45)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.updateApplication(ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.java:250)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationManagementAdminService.updateApplication(ApplicationManagementAdminService.java:120)
... 56 more


Kindly suggest if I am doing some thing wrong ?
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the application, you need to pass the complete service provider. It can't be updated partially. In the implementation, the update call will override the existing configurations with the configurations from the request. Here as you are only having the applicationId and the description other configurations will be missed. That's the reason for this error.

User [getApplication](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Using+the+Service+Provider+API#UsingtheServiceProviderAPI-getApplication) and replace the configuration changes and use it to update the application.